# Memory leak using Windows API EnumThreadWindows with List

Tags: c#, windows, memory-leaks, .net-core

I'm using EnumThreadWindows to find specific windows handles and update some list when I find it, for some reason when I use List inside the delegate I have memory leak

I checked it more than few times and when I comment the line that uses the list my memory usage is stable

```cs
var result = new List<SomeClass>();
WindowsNativeAPI.EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id, (hWnd, lParam) =>
  {
      if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) return true;                   
      result.Add(new SomeClass()); // If I comment this the memory leak is fixed                   
      return true;
  }, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Whenever I use the list inside the callback I can clearly see my memory usage increase, if I don't my memory is stable. 
Also its worth mentioning that this function is called many times when I enumerate through processes threads.

Edit: I've also noticed that it doesn't matter what I do with the list, even if I 
do this instead of result.Add:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
```

I still have memory leak

Edit2: I think I might have fixed it by doing this:

```cs
var foundHandles = new List<IntPtr>();
var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(foundHandles);
var lParam = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gch);
```

Then passing the list as lParam to the EnumThreadWindows and in the function I use:

```cs
var gcHandle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(lParam);
var list = gcHandle.Target as List<IntPtr>;
```

And in the end use:

```cs
gch.Free();
```

I also changed the list to IntPtr and create SomeClass later but that didn't help.
When I used GCHandle to pass my list, my memory is not rising anymore (I did tests for more than an hour to make sure)
Still I can't really understand why when using the List like before my program's memory increases without decreasing over time, so if someone knows why please explain:)

Edit3: I somehow forgot to mention that I'm using .Net Core 3 Preview 6, I don't think it matters since I just use the Win API

Edit4: Added some foundings:
You can try run this code, when I run the code without gc.Alloc the unmanaged memory is never cleared, even if I pause the program and wait

```cs
public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr 
[DllImport("user32", 
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.
public static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int threadId, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr 
static void Main(string[] 
{
   var a = true;
   while (a)
   {
     foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
     {
         foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
         {
             var list = new List<IntPtr>();

             EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id, (wnd, param) =>
             {
                 list.Add(wnd);
                 return true;
             }, IntPtr.Zero);
             thread.Dispose();

         }

         process.Dispose();
     }

     GC.Collect();
     Thread.Sleep(1);
   }
}
```

when I run this code I can see in DotMemory:
[Code without using GC.Alloc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KlLW.png)

Code with GC.Alloc

```cs
var list = new List<IntPtr>();
var aloc = GCHandle.Alloc(list);
var lParam = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(aloc);
EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id, (wnd, param) =>
  {
     var list1 = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(param).Target as List<IntPtr>;
     list1?.Add(wnd);
     return true;
  }, lParam);
thread.Dispose();
aloc.Free();
```

[DotMemory with GC.Alloc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dga8N.png)

I might not understand something basic but even though I don't have any problem now when I use GC.Alloc I still want to understand why this is happening. Thanks

Comment: What if you create a static (hWnd, lParam) => {} method?

Comment: It's not abnormal for your memory usage to increase when you add items to a list. How do you determine that the memory is leaking?

Comment: @JeroenHeier - I just tried it and it didn't work :( I had to change the list to static as well.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I stop using the List in the end of the function so it should be cleared by the GC. Also I determine the memory leak using DotMemory - I can see that my program's unmanaged memory keep increasing and never decrease, this also can be seen in the overall RAM my program takes

Comment: Nothing of that indicates a resource leak. You have opted to use a programming language with non-deterministic garbage collection. You should not expect deterministic garbage collection. This could still be a resource leak, but the evidence so far is not sufficient.

Comment: Are you sure that the garbage collector runs at all? The runtime might not run the garbage collector until it sees memory pressure. So the "leak" could very well be that the runtime hasn't yet determined that it needs to collect. Or perhaps your `SomeClass` constructor ends up making something else point to the new object, so those objects you create aren't collected. There are many possible reasons. Does DotMemory specifically say that these lists are the cause of your increasing memory use?

Comment: The questioner states that there is a leak even if he is using Console.WriteLine. Have a look at [GC.Collect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.8); see also the example code in order to test if that works. Any extra code in WindowsNativeAPI?

Comment: @JimMischel - Yes it is running.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I believe I fixed it now using this:
```c#
var foundHandles = new List<IntPtr>();
var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(foundHandles);
```
Then pass the pointer to the EnumThreadWindows as lParam.
Also I don't have any extra code in the WindowsAPI

Comment: Before trying to fix a problem, make sure that problem exists. So far there is no convincing evidence to support the assumption that there were a leak. Please provide evidence.

Comment: @IInspectable - I might be wrong, I am assuming it is memory leak because I can see my unmanaged memory keep increasing without ever decreasing. See my update in the main post please. Thanks

Comment: That's how a memory leak manifests itself. That's also the observable effect of a .NET program that doesn't have a defect. If you want to reliable diagnose a resource leak, check to see if your objects still have roots at a point where you expect them to be ready to get collected.

Comment: Also note that the screenshots illustrating your memory usage indicate, that your resource consumption is practically zero. The number of objects ready to be collected (Gen1 and Gen2) is close to nil. There's absolutely no reason for the CLR to run a pretty expensive operation like garbage collection. [Analyze .NET Framework memory issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/misc/analyze-dotnet-framework-memory-issues?view=vs-2015) explains, how to take out the guessing out of diagnosing resource leaks.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the reply, I used the GC.Collect just to make sure since this code was just to explain my point, I don't use it in my main code and I understand that it does nothing (Same results if I remove it). Still I can't understand why when I don't use GCHandle.Alloc my memory is rising so much without ever freeing. Also how do I check to see if my objects still have roots if my objects are unmanaged? Because I believe that when I pass the List<IntPtr> to the EnumWindowProc it creates some unmanaged representation of the List which is not cleared.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see your update earlier. This does indeed appear to be a resource leak. I don't think it's the `List<>`, though. I believe the real culprit here is the lambda, that eventually holds onto the list, but never gets released itself. [Why does a lambda expression in C# cause a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46962507/1889329) might offer some valuable insight into what's going on behind the scenes. I'm not a .NET developer, so don't take my word for it, but I'd look into who's holding onto the `List<>`. If indeed it is the lambda, take it from there.