# Memory leak when using Linq with a 'Where' clause and 'ToList()'

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, memory-leaks

I have the following method in my code in my `WPF` application that uses a `DataGrid`:

```
List<IColumn> GetColumns()
{
    return _columnItems
        .Where(column => column is TextColumn<T> textColumn && 
                         textColumn.IsColumnEnabled
        )
        .ToList();
}
```

This code remains in memory even after closing a dialog containing the corresponding `datagrid`. I can see it by examining `dotMemory` by `JetBrains`, I have a `Func<IColumn, bool>` as a GC root, holding on to my DataGrid.

Yet, if I just perform this simple change:

```
List<IColumn> GetColumns()
{
    var columnsToReturn = new List<IColumn>();
    foreach (var column in _columnItems)
    {
        if (column is TextColumn<T> textColumn && textColumn.IsColumnEnabled)
            columnsToReturn.Add(textColumn);
    }

    return columnsToReturn ;
}
```

The memory leak is gone, the instance of `DataGrid` is cleaned after closing the dialog, this `Func` that used to be a GC root is gone.

As much as I'm happy that I've resolved the memory leak, `I would like to understand what's going on?`

I assume it is related to `Linq` projection and it's logic of caching entries, though I'm a bit surprised as the leaking code has `ToList()` in the end, which was already supposed to execute the query. My long syntax escapes the `Linq` Func (Where), and thus "cutting off" the tree branch in `dotMemory`.

I mean, I already return the `Func` execution from this method, as I've already invoked `ToList()` , so whatever uses this method's output uses the returned list, so why would the `Func` still be kept in memory by `Linq` or `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Is it possible that in the first example the GC just takes longer to collect? That would be my first guess. If your application runs for a longer period can you check to see if the GC does it's job or if indeed this is a long-term leak?

Comment: @h0r53 Well, I've set a timer for 5 minutes, after closing the dialog, and then I've taken another snapshot (triggering GC.Collect), and I can still see the Func holding my DataGrid in memory. I even took another 2-3 snapshots (after those 5 minutes), to make sure this finalizer queue is cleared, and still the same when inspecting the very last snapshot. 

So, it looks like this Func is here to stay...

Comment: The copiler generates a class for every lambda in your code. Any variables captured by the lambda become instance members of this class. During runtime the class is instantiated and I believe once per execution of that lambda. I also believe there can't be any hidden references to that instance by design so as soon as the lambda has been executed it should be collected by the GC sooner or later. What you are seeing might just be a GC working a bit too slow.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Thank you for your reply.
Please see my comment above. It's already been 10 minutes after closing the dialog, I've even taken another 2 snapshots, and when examining the last one, I can still see the Func in memory. I think it's unlikely for GC to be slower than 10 minutes, right?

Comment: You might have some misconceptions on how the garbage collector works in general. If so this article from Raymond Chen might be a helpful read. [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203)

Comment: You could try a counter-example that could show the issue your are seeing is not related to `Func`s: allocate a noticeably large array of anything inside `GetColumns()` and maybe do some iterating over it to prevent its local variable from being optimized away. In your understanding it should be collected relatively soon after  `GetColumns()` finished. If not then the GC works differently then you assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, this is caused due to compiler optimization.

You can find all the related info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46963119/3707896

In short, the compiler created a child class, put my function (lambda expression) as an instance method of that class, created a singleton instance of that class in a static field and finally created a static field with my Func referencing my method. So, no surprise that those static members generated by compiler cannot be collected by GC.

***Credit to the original writer of the post in the attached link:*** @Evk